# How to get height of LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout set height as match_parent as below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

I want to get the height of this LinearLayout.
I used the code below:

```
LinearLayout ll_list = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.list_layout);
int h = ll_list.getHeight();
```

But it return null.
How can I do?

Comment: unless you're going to have a background task optimizing bitmaps (or something similar) before showing them on the screen, I really can't thing on any moment any would need this value. If you could tell us a bit more about your application, we might be able to point you to a better design alternative.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41705445/5664529 check this out, it may help you.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First of all: your `LinearLayout` id is `left_layout`, not `list_layout`.

Also, `ll_list.getHeight()` will return 0 (as well as `ll_list.getWidth()`) if it's not drawed yet.

Solution would be to get the height after your view is layouted:

```
ll_list.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
         int height = ll_list.getHeight();
    }
});
```

And make sure that your `ll_list` is `final`.

Comment: @brian it's not your problem. Just make sure that you're calling `getHeight()` after view is drawed.

Comment: @brian I've provided an example

Comment: Is there any way to force android to draw the layout. I need the layout height in onCreateView().

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearLayout ll_list = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.list_layout);
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: may be he typed wrong in the question. it wouldn't even compile if that was the case

Comment: see your xml file name and also change id and then check it

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait View to be initialized first use View Tree Observer it waits until the view is created check out this

[get layout height and width at run time android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068945/get-layout-height-and-width-at-run-time-android)