# how to Get the Value of fill_parent in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a fragment in which I am using a linearlayout which I inflate in onCreateView() method. The fragment is the right pane , which means my screen is divided into 2 fragments.
My Linear Layout is as follows:

```
 <LinearLayout
android:layout_Width = "fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
```

My issue is I will dynamically add views to this layout in onCreateView() method once I inflate this layout. Now I need to know the exact value of screenwidth this layout occupies before I add the  views to this layout. 
Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You want screen width ?

Comment: yes. Screenwidth in the sense LAyout occupied screenwidth

Comment: Why do you need the screenwidth?

Answer (score 1):

```
 l = (LinearLayout)findviewbyid(R.id.l1);
 ViewTreeObserver observer = l.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            init();
        l.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(
                this);
    }
});

protected void init() {
    int a= l.getHeight();
        int b = l.getWidth();
Toast.makeText(getActivity,""+a+" "+b,3000).show();
} 
callfragment();
}
```

Original [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068945/get-layout-height-and-width-at-run-time-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can give the LinearLayout and id and the use the getLayoutParams() on the LinearLayour Object to get the width

Comment: then I will get width as zero as onCreateView() is not returned