# ImageView use parent layout height

Tags: android, layout, imageview, scale, fill-parent

I'm having the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159320/how-to-size-an-android-view-based-on-its-parents-dimensions) but the answers there don't solve the problem. I've subclassed `ImageView`, and overriden `onMeasure` like so:

```
@Override 
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    this.setMeasuredDimension(this.getMeasuredHeight(), this.getMeasuredHeight());
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
```

This doesn't change anything, and if I try using the code from the answers of the linked post, the `ImageView` becomes invisible (0 width/height) because the heightMeasureSpec is 0, and `MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)` is also `0`.

The goal is to have the `ImageView` be as tall as the parent view, and have the width be the same (as the image is square).[image: Screenshot]

Edit: here is my ImageView in the layout XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bottomtext"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/toptext"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Comment: Why are you overriding onMeasure? Can't you just use `layout_height="match_parent"` in XML?

Comment: "match_parent" and "wrap_content" give the same results, which don't fill the height of the list item. I achieve this by using alignTop and alignBottom.

Answer (score 2):

use following field in ImageView

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't work. Above I'm using centerCrop scaletype which cuts the image's left and right edges off, and fitXY makes the image  width shrink and look distorted.

Answer (score 0):

No need to subclass the `ImageView'. Just do this

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/slider_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Comment: I don't want to set a width like this, I want it to match the height

Comment: I think the issue is that I'm using alignBottom and alignTop. height="match_parent" doesn't seem to work here, same size as using wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068945/get-layout-height-and-width-at-run-time-android),you can get the height of the layout at runtime. Get it and set it to imageview's width. And the image will become exact square.