# How to add TextView at below in a RelativeLayout when there is no space at right?

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I've seen many of questions for how to add `TextView` in a `RelativeLayout` programatically, but everybody adding it in `LinearLayout` with orientation vertical. Can any one suggest me or give me a link that how to add multiple `TextView` in `RelativeLayout` at right until it has space and then change the line.

I want a layout like this..
[image]

Comment: ankit use the layout params as you want those are margins

Comment: i'm using layout param, but either i use RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF or RelativeLayout.BELOW. how can i manage both togather.

Comment: [You can calculate currently filled layout width](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12212341/1777090) and check it with device width. if layout width about to exceed or exceeded device width, then `RelativeLayout.BELOW`, else use `RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF`

Comment: @PurpleDroid I've tried that code, but it returns the total width of device, not remaining width. (am i using it in correct way??).

Comment: @Ankit try setting wrap_content for relative layout, so that it just returns used width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this works for you !

You can customize [chips-edittext-library](https://github.com/kpbird/chips-edittext-library) for your need. Customizing by setting background to transparent, and editable to false.

-> Or you can use any other library which is used for displaying emoticon in EditText and customize it according to your need. Like [android-emoticon-edittext-spike](https://github.com/cblunt/android-emoticon-edittext-spike)

Comment: Thanks, I struggled with this:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Flow Layout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) library that manages the view arrangement itself.

When there is no space left the added `View` is moved to the next line

Comment: isn't there any easier way to do it, i'll messed up if i'll use it.

Comment: Sorry i don't know any other way