# Dynamically getting Height and Width of Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app I'm adding many views inside the Layout having below properties how shall i get the correct height of the layout at run time

```
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(840,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        ll.addView(view1); 
        ll.addView(view2);

        ll.getHeight();
```

how to  get Height of layout at that point consider adding of  view1 and view2 , irrespective of my property(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT), beacause it always return 0 to me?

Comment: may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068945/get-layout-height-and-width-at-run-time-android) is what you want

Comment: getMeasuredHeight() and getMeasuredWidth()

Comment: hey have you done this or not still?

Comment: @pratik yes I marked that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call

```
ll.post(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        ll.getHeight(); 
    }
});
```

This will give you `ll`'s height after adding the child views.

Comment: Sorry i don't know that.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
int width;
int height;

ll.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
   @Override
   public void onGlobalLayout() {
     width = view.getMeasuredWidth();
     height = view.getMeasuredHeight();

   }
});
```