# Android Viewgroup size very large by default

Tags: android

I have a view-group (`ZoomableViewGroup` is my custom class extending `ViewGroup`) in my layout as parent, which inside contains a relative layout.  The width and height of `ViewGroup` is by default 2286 height and 1600 width which is larger than device size.  How to set the `ViewGroup` size to screen size ? My final expected result is, I am trying to zoom and pan the relative out, it moves out of screen due to the huge size of `ViewGroup`.

```
<com.example.pdoc.zoomablepdf.ZoomableViewGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/zoomLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/samplebg"
        android:id="@+id/RelLayout">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/LinLayout">
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</com.example.pdoc.zoomablepdf.ZoomableViewGroup>
```

Java code

```
ZoomableViewGroup mZoomableViewGroup;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainnew);

    mZoomableViewGroup = (ZoomableViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.zoomLayout);

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinLayout);
    //add edittext dynamically
            EditText myText = new EditText(MainnewActivity.this);
            myText.setText("Edit Me");
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp.gravity= Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
            ll.addView(myText, lp);
    //add checkbox dynamically
            CheckBox myChk = new CheckBox(MainnewActivity.this);
            myChk.setText("Check me");
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams chklp = new
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            chklp.gravity= Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
            ll.addView(myChk, chklp);
    //add imageview dynamically
        ImageView myImg = new ImageView(MainnewActivity.this);
        myImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams imgLP = new
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        imgLP.gravity= Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        ll.addView(myImg, imgLP);
    //add button dynamically
        Button mybtn1 = new Button(MainnewActivity.this);
        mybtn1.setText("Click me");
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams btnLP = new
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        btnLP.gravity= Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        ll.addView(mybtn1, btnLP);

        mybtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
               Toast.makeText(MainnewActivity.this, "6--"+ mZoomableViewGroup.getHeight() + "_" + mZoomableViewGroup.getWidth(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

ZoomableViewGroup class code

```
public class ZoomableViewGroup extends ViewGroup {

// States.
private static final byte NONE = 0;
private static final byte DRAG = 1;
private static final byte ZOOM = 2;
private static final byte DTAP = 3;

private byte mode = NONE;

// Matrices used to move and zoom image.
private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
private Matrix matrixInverse = new Matrix();
private Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

// Parameters for zooming.
private PointF start = new PointF();
private PointF mid = new PointF();
private float oldDist = 1f;
private float[] lastEvent = null;
private long lastDownTime = 0l;

private float[] mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray = new float[2];
private float[] mOnTouchEventWorkingArray = new float[2];

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[0] = ev.getX();
    mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[1] = ev.getY();
    mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray = screenPointsToScaledPoints(mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray);
    ev.setLocation(mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[0], mDispatchTouchEventWorkingArray[1]);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
public ZoomableViewGroup(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Toast.makeText(context, "c1-" + this.getHeight() + "_" + this.getWidth(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
    init(context);
}
public ZoomableViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Toast.makeText(context, "c2-" + this.getHeight() + "_" + this.getWidth(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
    init(context);
}
public ZoomableViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    Toast.makeText(context, "c3-" + this.getHeight() + "_" + this.getWidth(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
    init(context);
}
private void init(Context context) {
}

//Determine the space between the first two fingers
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

//Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers
private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}

private float[] scaledPointsToScreenPoints(float[] a) {
    matrix.mapPoints(a);
    return a;
}

private float[] screenPointsToScaledPoints(float[] a) {
    matrixInverse.mapPoints(a);
    return a;
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    //super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    int childCount = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
            child.layout(child.getLeft(), child.getTop(), child.getLeft()+child.getMeasuredWidth(), child.getTop()+child.getMeasuredHeight());
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    //measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int childCount = getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
            measureChild(child, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
    //measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    float[] values = new float[9];
    matrix.getValues(values);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(values[Matrix.MTRANS_X], values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]);
    canvas.scale(values[Matrix.MSCALE_X], values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]);
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // handle touch events here
    mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[0] = event.getX();
    mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[1] = event.getY();
    mOnTouchEventWorkingArray = scaledPointsToScreenPoints(mOnTouchEventWorkingArray);
    event.setLocation(mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[0], mOnTouchEventWorkingArray[1]);

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            mode = DRAG;
            lastEvent = null;
            long downTime = event.getDownTime();
            if (downTime - lastDownTime < 300l) {
                float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                if (Math.max(Math.abs(start.x - event.getX()), Math.abs(start.y - event.getY())) < 20.f * density) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    mid.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    mode = ZOOM;
                    lastEvent = new float[4];
                    lastEvent[0] = lastEvent[1] = event.getX();
                    lastEvent[2] = lastEvent[3] = event.getY();
                }
                lastDownTime = 0l;
            } else {
                lastDownTime = downTime;
            }
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            if (oldDist > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
            }
            lastEvent = new float[4];
            lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
            lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
            lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
            lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            lastEvent = null;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                float dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                float dy = event.getY() - start.y;

                RelativeLayout Rel = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelLayout);
                //getGlobalVisibleRect(Rel);
                ZoomableViewGroup ZVG = (ZoomableViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.zoomLayout);
                Rel.getTop();
                Rel.getY();
                //if(dx > 0) dx=0;
                //if(dy > 0) dy=0;
               //Toast.makeText(getContext(), dx + "_" + dy + "REL=" + Rel.getTop()+"_"+ Rel.getLeft(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                //Toast.makeText(getContext(), ZVG.getHeight() + "-" + ZVG.getWidth(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
                matrix.invert(matrixInverse);
                if (Math.max(Math.abs(start.x - event.getX()), Math.abs(start.y - event.getY())) > 20.f * density) {
                    lastDownTime = 0l;
                }
            } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                if (event.getPointerCount() > 1) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    if (newDist > 10f * density) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = (newDist / oldDist);

                        //to restrict the min zoom not tobe less than screen size
                        float[] values = new float[9];
                        matrix.getValues(values);
                        if(scale*values[matrix.MSCALE_X] <= 1)
                        { scale = 1/values[matrix.MSCALE_X]; }
                        //till here
                        //condition to check maximum zoom scale to 10
                        if(scale * values[matrix.MSCALE_X] <10)
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                        matrix.invert(matrixInverse);
                    }
                } else {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = event.getY() / start.y;

                    //to restrict the min zoom to 1 or not less than screen size
                    float[] values = new float[9];
                    matrix.getValues(values);
                    if(scale*values[matrix.MSCALE_Y] <= 1)
                    { scale = 1/values[matrix.MSCALE_Y]; }
                    //till here
                    //condition to check maximum zoom scale to 10
                    if(scale * values[matrix.MSCALE_Y] <10)
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    matrix.invert(matrixInverse);
                }
            }
            break;

    }

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps . Try to Set the height and width of viewgroup dynamically.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
ZoomableViewGroup layout= (ZoomableViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.zoomLayout);
int width=display.getWidth();
int height=display.getHeight();
FrameLayout.LayoutParams parms = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
layout.setLayoutParams(parms);
```

Comment: I just want it to be the size of screen only...say equivalent to size of relativelayout which is in viewgroup..

Comment: Adjust width and height according to relativelayout width and height. Get height and width of relativelayout and set it to your main layout.[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12068945/get-layout-height-and-width-at-run-time-android]

Comment: Even the size of relativelayout is same as in layout it's height and width are set to matchparent..