# getHeight() of layout returns zero by ViewTreeObserver

Tags: android

I am using **ViewTreeObserver** in **OnCreate** method to get height of my toolbar and bottom layout but still I am getting **0 height**, why? Am I doing something wrong?

This is how I am calling:

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = toolbar.getViewTreeObserver();
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // Ensure you call it only once :
                toolbar.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                height1 = toolbar.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
        });

        final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottom);
        ViewTreeObserver vto = linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // Ensure you call it only once :
                linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                height2 = linearLayout.getMeasuredHeight();

            }
        });

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(height1) + String.valueOf(height2), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Did you try getWidth() or getHeight() with handler? Here is sample:
new Handler().postDelayed( new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    height1 = toolbar.getMeasuredHeight();
    height2 = linearLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
   }
  }, 1000 );

Comment: I tried this one also but no solution.

Comment: What if layout got 0 height? Do you sure that layout is visible? I ask that because I missed this before in my project.

Comment: Yeah layout is visible I gave fix height from xml, after turning off my screen I am getting value of layout but not on when activity start.

Comment: If you want to get layout height when screen turns off, this means activity is onPause state. So all layouts have 0 height. Did I understand wrong?

Comment: No @MetehanToksoy, I want to get height on start activity and I am not getting at that time, But I do screen off and then on at that time I am getting value.

Answer (score 21):

Looks like your layout has to make more than one measure/layout pass, and the pieces of layout have zero dimensions after the first pass. Try to remove `OnGlobalLayoutListener` only when you have positive dimensions. Something like this:

```
if (linearLayout.getMeasuredHeight() > 0) {
    linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean remove OnGlobalLayoutListener? do I have to get directly height? if so then I am not getting any value.

Comment: I did like this but no solution: `@Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (linearLayout.getMeasuredHeight() > 0) {
                    height2 = linearLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
                    linearLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener((ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener) this);
                }
            }`

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue, but reason is not the same as @aga answer. The problem is my view is hidden when activity is initialized (inside onCreate). And I just move the code that show/hide my view after the layout size calculation is completed for it to work as expected. Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

**OnGlobalLayoutListener** is work on **ViewTreeObserver**, and its method **onGlobalLayout** does not called immediately. This Listener only works on some event occurred in current layout (when some changes is shown to the listener). so, you get **0 height** when you load your layout.

if you want to access this value outside **ViewTreeObserver** the solution is this:

```
private int height;

ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = toolbar.getViewTreeObserver();
viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        height = toolbar.getMeasuredHeight();
        setHeight(height);
        // Ensure you call it only once :
        toolbar.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }
});

private void setHeight(int h) {
    this.height = h;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(height), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```