# How do I overlap three equally-sized views with smaller views between them?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml, android-framelayout

I am trying to make three buttons equally-spaced and aligned vertically with circles overlapping between them like so:

[image: Three buttons with circles between them]

I ran into difficulties because a LinearLayout was needed to equally weight the three buttons, but overlapping views are most easily done in RelativeLayout and FrameLayout (I need to support <21 SDK, so I can't use z-index with LinearLayout).

When I put the "OR" circles in the Frame/RelativeLayouts, there's no easy way to set them at 1/3rd the view height so that they fall in between the  buttons.

How do I divide a FrameLayout with the OR circles into thirds to properly place the circles?

Comment: I almost had it with PercentRelativeLayout and negative margins for the "or"s, but even with code I still couldn't get those buggers to show up in front of the buttons.

Comment: Huh, I've never used PercentRelativeLayout... As long as the the top most view in the display is at the bottom of the RelativeLayout, it should be displayed on top?

Comment: That's what I did, but they were still underneath the buttons anyway.  I think it has to do with the fact that the buttons are clickable and the textviews aren't.  I even tried `bringToFront()` but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have did following xml coding and generate similar out put

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:gravity="center"
         >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="dd"
            android:background="#CCCCCC"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="dd"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="#CCCCCC"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="dd"
            android:background="#CCCCCC"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:text="OR"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:text="OR"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />
        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: just try to paste this code in your xml it should work. i have did in my xml

Comment: Tested and it's working perfectly just with the XML. It is not interfering with the buttons in my layout at all.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a straightforward solution to this, so I'm answering my own question! Please let me know if you have a better solution.

The solution I came up with was to layout the buttons in a `LinearLayout` inside a `FrameLayout` and weight them properly. The OR circles are placed in the `FrameLayout` after the buttons, so that they will be drawn on top. However, they are not positioned in the xml.

In `onCreate()` I measured the drawn size of the `LinearLayout` with buttons and then moved the OR circles by one third plus the radius of the circle.

Here is the relevant XML. The key points are:

- `FrameLayout` wrapper, matching parent for full area buttons to be shown.
- `LinearLayout` wrapper for buttons, matching parent.
- `Button` heights all set to `0dp` and `layout_weight="1"`
- `TextViews` for OR circles centered horizontally, but not adjusted vertically. Note their diameter is `30dp`

  ```
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:id="@+id/buttons_container">

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/record_topic_option_1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="topic1"
          android:theme="@style/PrimaryButton"/>

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/record_topic_option_2"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
          android:onClick="topic2"
          android:theme="@style/PrimaryButton" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/record_topic_option_3"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:onClick="topic3"
          android:theme="@style/PrimaryButton" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/top_or"
      android:layout_width="30dp"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:text="OR"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:textSize="@dimen/material_text_caption"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:background="@drawable/or_circle_background"
      />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/bottom_or"
      android:layout_width="30dp"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="OR"
      android:textSize="@dimen/material_text_caption"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:background="@drawable/or_circle_background" />
  ```

Once that is set up, the trick is to adjust the circles programmatically in `onCreate()`

```
final View buttonContainer = findViewById(R.id.buttons_container);
View topOr = findViewById(R.id.top_or);
View bottomOr = findViewById(R.id.bottom_or);

//Get the 15dp radius in pixels at the current screen density.
final int added_height_for_radius = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
15, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

//Use a ViewTreeObserver to make sure that the view is drawn and you get an accurate measurement of the LinearLayout with buttons
buttonContainer.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
        new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int width = buttonContainer.getWidth();
        int height = buttonContainer.getHeight();

        //Moving the topOr and bottomOr by setting the top margin to height/3-radius and 2*height/3-radius
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)topOr.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(0, (height/3)-added_height_for_radius, 0, 0);
        topOr.setLayoutParams(params);

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params2 = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)bottomOr.getLayoutParams();
        params2.setMargins(0, (2*height/3)-added_height_for_radius, 0, 0);
        bottomOr.setLayoutParams(params2);
        buttonContainer.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }
});
```

Thanks to 
[Get height and width of a layout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926644/get-height-and-width-of-a-layout-programatically)