# Linearlayout getHeight() return 0 but inside setOnClickListener return true value

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

Edit: Meant to ask "Why does it work inside setOnClickListener", but found it shortly after.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21926714/6474462

Old:
Was playing with the ObjectAnimator and noticed the LinearLayout getHeight() return 0, but inside the setOnClickListener(after click) do actually return the true value, how does this work?

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_linear);

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        final TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);

        int viewHeight1 = linearLayout.getHeight();
        textView1.setText("viewHeight1: " + viewHeight1);

        textView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int viewHeight2 = linearLayout.getHeight();
                textView2.setText("viewHeight2: " + viewHeight2);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call getHeight() after the object draw on screen

```
final TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
final ViewTreeObserver object= textView1 .getViewTreeObserver();
   object.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
          textView1 .getHeight()
          object.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
```