# Finding the Value of a Layout's Height and Width

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to get the height and width of a table layout and use that to set the height and width of my buttons. I use the following code to achieve this:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();
params.width = params.width/3;
params.height = params.width;
```

The code however does not work and I am unsure as of to why.

Comment: are you facing any error or an exception ?

Comment: Maybe the answer is here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926644/get-height-and-width-of-a-layout-programmatically

Comment: Are you setting the params to the view? like `view.setLayoutParams(params)` also you have not defined `width` and `height` parameters in layout params therefore it would be `0/3` and `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when `onCreate` is executed in your `Activity`, the `UI` has not been drawn to the screen yet, so nothing has dimensions yet since they haven't been laid out on the screen.
When `setContentView` is called, a message is posted to the `UI` thread to draw the `UI` for your layout, but will happen in the future after onCreate finishes executing.
Posting a `Runnable` to the `UI` thread will put the `Runnable` at the end of the message queue for the `UI` thread, so will be executed after the screen has been drawn,thus everything has dimensions. (that's why you got a NullPointerException from `Niza Siwale` answer)

```
btn.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TableLayout myTableLayout = findViewById(R.id.idOfTheTableLayout);
            int width = myTableLayout.getWidth();
            int height = myTableLaout.getHeight();

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = btn.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = height;
            params.width = width;
            btn.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
}
```

hope it works.

Comment: What is a Runnable and how do I use it?

Comment: after initializing your button in the onCreate method (Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btnId)) you can then use the code I posted (inside the onCreate method).  As I mentioned in my explanation Runnable is used to separate your code. That way you make sure to get the width and hight only after the screen was drawn. Otherwise you always trying to get the dimensions of a null object because it wasn't initialized yet.

Comment: Thank you, this worked great!

Answer (score 4):

You're using the same params Object which are also empty.
Your code should be like this

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams btnParams = btn.getLayoutParams();

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = tableLayout.getLayoutParams();
btnParams.width = params.width/3;
btnParams.height = params.width;
btn.setLayoutParams(btnParams)
```

Comment: When I do that, my app crashes and I get this error message: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.width' on a null object reference

Comment: Is your tableLayout initialized? i.e does it have a parent with a context?

Comment: I set up my table view in the activity_main.xml file, so I think it's initialized.

Comment: What about your button?

Comment: My button is set up as `Button b = new Button(this);`

Comment: You have to add it to a view after you create the button. The params come from the layouts parent. Add your button to a parent first

Comment: Even after I add the buttons, the app still crashes.