# How to "properly" retrieve a LinearLayout's height from onCreateView() in a Fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, layout, height

**Problem description:**
I need to set the height of a `ScrollView` equal to n times the height of an inner horizontal `LinearLayout`,  inside `onCreateView()` and in a fragment.
I dynamically add `ImageView`'s inside the `LinearLayout`, so the height is not fixed.

**Possible solutions:**
I’ve been doing some research and there seems to be at least two solutions that are repeated:

1. Using a `Runnable` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55180559/14230540)).
2. Using a `ViewTreeObserver` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21926714/14230540)).

**Is there any other more elegant/simpler/correct way to tackle this in 2020?**
In case there isn’t, which way do you suggest me to go?

**Basics:**
In `onCreateView()` I’m able to assign any value to the height of the `ScrollView`, and that works fine.

```
override fun onCreateView(...) {
//Some other unrelated code

binding.MyScrollView.layoutParams.height = 100

}
```

..but unfortunately I don't have a fixed value.

I need to retrieve the `LinearLayout`'s height, but as you know, it's not created yet in `onCreateView()`.

```
val layoutHeight = binding.MyLinearLayout.height //returns 0
```

And that is what I need to solve.

Just in case, I’m using Kotlin.

Comment: can you give some more info? Can you post your XML here?

Comment: @TejasDhawale, thanks for your interest. The XML should be irrelevant in this case.