# How can I get wrap_content or match_parent layout width and height using kotlin in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to get my layout or view (not screen size) width an height in some android devices, so how can I do this? For example:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:paddingRight="8dp"
     android:paddingLeft="8dp"
     android:id="@+id/layout_scrol_left"/>
```

I have this layout and I want to get layout width and height size (in dip) in runtime, how can I do that?

Comment: possibly relate this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926644/get-height-and-width-of-a-layout-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

```html
val myView = findViewById<View>(R.id.my_view)
val layoutParams = myView.layoutParams
layoutParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
layoutParams.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
myView.layoutParams = layoutParams
```