# Get the height of dynamically added LinearLayouts in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-linearlayout

I am working in an android application and I am adding a Linear Layout dynamically in my Scollview. Now I want to get the height of each Linear Layout added dynamically . Below is my code and Xml.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.subscrollLinearLayout);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    List<String> mSempLog = new ArrayList<String>();

    mSempLog.add("TEST1");
    mSempLog.add("TEST2");
    mSempLog.add("TEST3");
    mSempLog.add("TEST4");
    mSempLog.add("TEST5");
    mSempLog.add("TEST6");
    mSempLog.add("TEST7");
    mSempLog.add("TEST8");

    for (int i = 0; i < mSempLog.size(); i++) {

        LinearLayout service_row = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.tesffff, null);
        TextView dd = ((TextView) service_row.findViewById(R.id.test1));
        dd.setText(mSempLog.get(i));
        dd.setTag(i);
        ((TextView) service_row.findViewById(R.id.test2)).setText(mSempLog
                .get(i));

        layout.addView(service_row, i);

    }

    ScrollView parentScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.parentscroll);
    ScrollView childScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.subscroll);

    parentScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            findViewById(R.id.subscroll).getParent()
                    .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            return false;
        }
    });

    childScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of
            // child view
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentscroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/subscroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/subscrollLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dfsdfsdf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dfsdfsdf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dfsdfsdf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dfsdfsdf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dfsdfsdf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dfsdfsdf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dfsdfsdf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dfsdfsdf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="dfsdfsdf" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Row xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onTest1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onTest2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It might be useful:
[How to get height of LinearLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11964499/how-to-get-height-of-linearlayout)

Comment: Have you consider using a ListView with your own adapter ?
Btw, you should not have a ScrollView inside a ScrollView

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
MyListViewObj.post(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
         int height = MyListViewObj.getHeight();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can get width by few ways.

- case 1: yourView.getHeight() (only when the view was already drawn)
- case 2: yourView.getLayoutParams().height (depends on LayoutParams)
- case 3: http://www.limbaniandroid.com/2014/10/viewtreeobserver-how-to-get-layout.html
- case 4: If you have custom layout then you can get height in onMeasure (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int,
  int))